# Load GWT app in a div

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I'm fairly new to GWT. I have some HTML markup along with CSS generated. I want to load my GWT app within a specific div within the host HTML however I'm running into some trouble. Whenever the app loads it automatically adds the GWT app to the bottom of the html and not in the DIV I want.

Comment: can you show your Java code and the Host page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using correctly method [RootPanel.get(String id)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RootPanel.html#get%28java.lang.String%29)?

```
RootPanel.get("myDiv").add(myWidget);
```

where `"myDiv"` is id of your div and `myWidget` is your GWT widget.